# NestJS Cron unit test with deleteCronJob()

Tags: unit-testing, testing, cron, nestjs

I created a unit test for a NestJS according to: [How to write a unit test for CronJob in Nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71469500/how-to-write-a-unit-test-for-cronjob-in-nestjs)

```
@Injectable()
export class CronService {

  private readonly logger = new Logger(CronService.name)

  constructor(private schedulerRegistry: SchedulerRegistry) { }

  async addCronJob(name: string, cronTime: string, cronAction: () => void | Promise<void>): Promise<void> { 
    const job = new CronJob(cronTime, cronAction)

    this.schedulerRegistry.addCronJob(name, job)
    job.start()

    this.logger.log(
      `Cron job '${name}' added with cron time ${cronTime}!`,
    )
  }

  deleteCron(name: string) {
    this.schedulerRegistry.deleteCronJob(name);
    this.logger.log(`Cron job '${name}' deleted!`);
  }

}
```

Testing:

```
describe('CronModule', () => {

let cronService: CronService;
let schedulerRegistryMock: SchedulerRegistry

beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
        providers: [
            CronService,
            {
                provide: SchedulerRegistry,
                useValue: createMock<SchedulerRegistry>()

            },
            {
                provide: Logger,
                useValue: {
                    log: jest.fn()
                }        
            }
        ],
    }).compile()

    cronService = moduleRef.get<CronService>(CronService)
    schedulerRegistryMock = moduleRef.get<SchedulerRegistry>(SchedulerRegistry)
    logger = moduleRef.get<Logger>(Logger)
})

describe('addAndDeleteCronJob', () => {
    it('Should add and delete cron job', async () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers()
        const name: string = 'TestCronJob'
        const cronTime: string = '0 * * * *'
        const cronAction: () => void = jest.fn(() => logger.log('Task executed!'))

        await cronService.addCronJob(name, cronTime, cronAction)

        expect(cronAction).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
        expect(schedulerRegistryMock.addCronJob).toHaveBeenCalledWith(name, expect.any(CronJob))

        jest.advanceTimersByTime(60 * 60 * 1000)
        expect(cronAction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

        cronService.deleteCron(name)

        jest.advanceTimersByTime(60 * 60 * 1000)
        expect(cronAction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

    })
})
```

})

The test for creating the job works good!

But testing deletion of the cron job `deleteCron()` seems not to work, as the second `expect(cronAction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` after `jest.advanceTimersByTime(60 * 60 * 1000)` receives 2 calls of `cronAction()`.
How should I test the deletion of the cron job?